# jgit commit throws PGP Exception

Tags: java, eclipse, jgit

I am trying to execute git commit operation in Java using Eclipse IDE.
The code to perform commit operation is as follows:-

```
public RevCommit commit(String message,boolean setAll) throws GitAPIException 
{
    RevCommit revCommit = null;
    CommitCommand command = git.commit();
    command.setCredentialsProvider(credentials);
    command.setMessage(message);
    if(setAll)
        command.setAll(true);
    try 
    {
        revCommit = command.call();
    } 
    catch (GitAPIException e) 
    {
        throw e;
    }
    out.println("Created a commit with message: " + message);
    return revCommit;
}
```

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/bouncycastle/openpgp/PGPException
    at org.eclipse.jgit.lib.GpgSigner.<clinit>(GpgSigner.java:58)
    at org.eclipse.jgit.api.CommitCommand.processOptions(CommitCommand.java:611)
    at org.eclipse.jgit.api.CommitCommand.call(CommitCommand.java:195)
    at vnbs.JenkinsIntegration.Platforms.Git_Interface.commit(Git_Interface.java:278)
    at vnbs.JenkinsIntegration.Platforms.Git_InterfaceTest.testCommit(Git_InterfaceTest.java:252)
```

Comment: Are references to PGPException in this file? Like an import?

Comment: The [Bouncy Castle](http://bouncycastle.org/) dependency is missing which is used by JGit to sign commits.